# How does Facebook Access Token used to Access Facebook User details?

Tags: facebook, security

Facebook discovered a "security issue" affecting 50 million accounts.

According to Facebook,

> This allowed them to steal Facebook access tokens which they could
>   then use to take over people’s accounts

I searched this about, but I couldn't find any single article, how to access Facebook account if you know the access token.

So I couldn't understand this security issue. Can anyone tell me how a hacker can access Facebook account if they know the access token?

Comment: you cannot access the facebook account, you can access some data, depending on the user token.

Comment: @luschn Then how we can read even chat messages using FB / Messenger Android App? (I think Facebook uses the user token for that)

Comment: then it´s not a simple user token but something proprietary from facebook. there is no way for you to read chat messages of user profiles. i am not sure what your question is, to be honest. only facebook would be able to answer your questions, and there is nothing you can do with the information. for you it´s only important to secure your access tokens in your app - for example, to use appsecret_proof server side.